# How to use T-SQL MERGE in this case?

Tags: sql, t-sql, merge, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm new to T-SQL command `MERGE` so I found a place in my SQL logic where I can use it and want to test it but can't figure out how exactly should I use it:

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM commissions_history WHERE request = @requestID))
    UPDATE commissions_history
    SET amount = @amount
    WHERE request = @requestID
ELSE
    INSERT INTO commissions_history (amount) VALUES @amount)
```

Please suggest the proper usage. Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Did you look in the help? Here's a simple example:

```
MERGE dbo.commissions_history AS target
USING (SELECT @amount, @requestID) AS source (amount, request)
ON (target.request = source.request)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET amount = source.amount
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (request, amount)
    VALUES (source.request, source.amount);
```

Comment: Here is a simple walkthrough of your simple example :)   http://stackoverflow.com/a/10219581/261997

Answer (score 1):

I hope it will work

```
MERGE commissions_history AS target
USING (SELECT request FROM  commissions_history WHERE request = @requestID) AS source (request)
ON (target.request = source.request)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET amount = @amount
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE    
    INSERT (request, amount)
    VALUES (@requestID,  @amount)
```

Comment: The insert part of that won't work, because your source select will return an empty recordset, which it will then try to merge

Comment: In the update, source.amount is from the taable commisions_history, but needs to be from the variable @Amount.

Comment: @Tom H, @Shannon Severance:
 Thanks for comments. I've changed it. Anyway, Tom H's is more clear.