# SQL Server 2008 - IF NOT EXISTS INSERT ELSE UPDATE

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I apologize, but this is kind of a two part question.

I'm extremely new to SQL and am trying to develop a time clock application for the small office that I work in. I'm playing around with the SQL backend right now and have a question about compound statements.

Where I'm stuck is if a user tries to clock out for break but never clocked in at the start of the shift, SQL needs to create a new row rather than update an existing.

Here is what I tried:

```
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Clock WHERE clockDate = '08/10/2012') AND userName = 'test')
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Clock(clockDate, userName, breakOut)
        VALUES({ fn NOW() }, 'test', { fn NOW() })
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Clock
        SET breakOut = { fn NOW() }
        WHERE (clockDate = '08/10/2012') AND (userName = 'test')
    END
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 to do this connected to SQL Server Express 2008 on my local machine. I get an error that says "The Compound statement SQL construct or statement is not supported." However, that is followed by a message that 1 row has been affected, and when I view my Clock table it looks just like what I expect it to look like. What is the best way to acclompish this?

And my second part of this question is in my WHERE statements. Is there a function to get today's date in the clockDate column rather than have to populate today's date? Just trying to think ahead for building the front end application.

```
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Clock WHERE clockDate = { fn CURRENT_DATE() }) AND userName = 'test')
```

Again, this gives me the results I want, but not until after getting an error "Error in WHERE clause near 'CURRENT_DATE'. Unable to parse query text."

I hope I have explained this properly, and thank you for your help!!

EDIT:

@RThomas
@w00te

OK, so with the clockDate as a date field and breakOut as a time(0) field, should this work? Cause I'm still getting a "The Compound statement SQL construct or statement is not supported." Syntax error even though it seems to be working.

```
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Clock WHERE (clockDate = GETDATE()) AND (userName = 'test'))
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Clock(clockDate, userName, breakOut)
        Values(GETDATE(), 'test', GETDATE())
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Clock
        SET breakOut = GETDATE()
        WHERE (clockDate = GETDATE()) AND (userName = 'test')
    END
```

My table results are:

```
clockDate  userName  clockIn  breakOut  breakIn  clockOut

08/10/2012  test      NULL    11:24:38   NULL     NULL
```

This is the result I want but this error confuses me. Is this a Visual Studio error or a SQL error? And I'll read up on Merge Statements, thank you both for the links.

Comment: Check out the [Merge](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement.

Comment: Despite my answer below, I agree with the others about a merge statement being a great way to handle insert/update scenarios when you're not sure if the value is already there or not.  Here is a walkthrough of the merge statement that I posted awhile back.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10218101/extremely-simple-t-sql-merge-example-needed-to-help-comprehension/10219581#10219581 if you want to learn more about how it works.

Comment: This is what exactly MERGE statement is used for! Check it out http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

Comment: Note that in some cases, especially with large data sets, the merge statement can be prohibitively slow, causing a lot of tran log activity.  So knowing how to logic it out is still valid.

Answer (score 70):

At first glance your original attempt seems pretty close.  I'm assuming that clockDate is a DateTime fields so try this:

```
IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Clock WHERE cast(clockDate as date) = '08/10/2012') 
    AND userName = 'test') 
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO Clock(clockDate, userName, breakOut) 
    VALUES(GetDate(), 'test', GetDate()) 
END 
ELSE 
BEGIN 
    UPDATE Clock 
    SET breakOut = GetDate()
    WHERE Cast(clockDate AS Date) = '08/10/2012' AND userName = 'test'
END
```

Note that getdate gives you the current date.  If you are trying to compare to a date (without the time) you need to cast or the time element will cause the compare to fail.

---

If clockDate is NOT datetime field (just date), then the SQL engine will do it for you - no need to cast on a set/insert statement.

```
IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Clock WHERE clockDate = '08/10/2012') 
    AND userName = 'test') 
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO Clock(clockDate, userName, breakOut) 
    VALUES(GetDate(), 'test', GetDate()) 
END 
ELSE 
BEGIN 
    UPDATE Clock 
    SET breakOut = GetDate()
    WHERE clockDate = '08/10/2012' AND userName = 'test'
END
```

As others have pointed out, the merge statement is another way to tackle this same logic.  However, in some cases, especially with large data sets, the merge statement can be prohibitively slow, causing a lot of tran log activity.  So knowing how to logic it out as shown above is still a valid technique.

Comment: clockDate is a 'date' data type NOT 'datetime'. Sorry for not clarifying that.

Comment: you can drop the cast statements then... I'll add to my post.

Comment: Oh and breakOut is a 'time(0)' field

Comment: That's ok.  `SET breakOut = GetDate()` will still update to the current time.  Just be aware that if you want to compare the values (instead of setting a value) you'll need to cast first like this... `where cast(getdate() as time(0)) = breatOut`.

Comment: To put it a different way.  You can set date, datetime, and time to getdate().  The sql engine is smart enough to do the conversion work for you.  It's just when comparing the value that you have to get more specific.

Answer (score 37):

> *As others have suggested that you should look into MERGE statement but nobody provided a solution using it I'm adding my own answer with this particular TSQL construct. I bet you'll like it.*

#### Important note

Your code has a typo in your `if` statement in `not exists(select...)` part. Inner `select` statement has only one `where` condition while UserName condition is excluded from the `not exists` due to invalid brace completion. In any case you cave too many closing braces.

I assume this based on the fact that you're using two `where` conditions in `update` statement later on in your code.

Let's continue to my answer...

### SQL Server 2008+ support MERGE statement

[MERGE statement](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) is a beautiful TSQL gem very well suited for *"insert or update"* situations. In your case it would look similar to the following code. Take into consideration that I'm declaring variables what are likely stored procedure parameters (I suspect).

```
declare @clockDate date = '08/10/2012';
declare @userName = 'test';

merge Clock as target
using (select @clockDate, @userName) as source (ClockDate, UserName)
on (target.ClockDate = source.ClockDate and target.UserName = source.UserName)
when matched then
    update
    set BreakOut = getdate()
when not matched then
    insert (ClockDate, UserName, BreakOut)
    values (getdate(), source.UserName, getdate());
```

Comment: I have some reserve in finding MERGE beautiful.

Comment: All good until you try to use MERGE on a remote table.. <face palm>  Why!?!?

Answer (score 6):

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Clock
WHERE clockDate = '08/10/2012') AND userName = 'test')
```

Has an extra parenthesis.  I think it's fine if you remove it:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Clock WHERE
clockDate = '08/10/2012' AND userName = 'test')
```

Also, GETDATE() will put the current date in the column, though if you don't want the time you'll have to play a little.  I think CONVERT(varchar(8), GETDATE(), 112) would give you just the date (not time) portion.

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Clock WHERE
clockDate = CONVERT(varchar(8), GETDATE(), 112)
AND userName = 'test')
```

should probably do it.

PS: use a [merge](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CF4QFjAA&url=http://www.bidn.com/blogs/bretupdegraff/bidn-blog/239/using-the-new-tsql-merge-statement-with-sql-server-2008&ei=g0YlUIctgsjrAcLZgYAP&usg=AFQjCNGYNGMEgAsIKfVS924nVYhqw38ySw&sig2=xkgEdg-HKsG0tXvFSQCN5A) statement :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace it as `WHERE clockDate = { fn CURRENT_DATE() } AND userName = 'test'`.
Please remove extra  `")"` from `{ fn CURRENT_DATE() })`

Comment: Sorry this was just a typo on my part. I do have it correct in my SQL query window.