# SQL stored procedure IF EXISTS UPDATE ELSE INSERT

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, if-statement

OK. I got a lot of help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906506/sql-server-2008-if-not-exists-insert-else-update) earlier working with a SQL backend to a simple ... just not for me :( ... time clock solution for the small office I work in, so I'm back for more!

My table I'm currently working with consists of 6 columns:

1. clockDate date not null PK
2. userName varchar(50) not null PK
3. clockIn time(0)
4. breakOut time(0)
5. breakIn time(0)
6. clockOut time(0)

I though I had figured out my `IF NOT EXISTS INSERT ELSE UPDATE` statement from my last question, but now I'm trying to use it in a Stored Procedure, rather than a plain query window, with no success.

Basically a user clocking in is a no-brainer. However, if the user doesn't clock in, but they clock out for lunch, the statement needs to create the row instead of updating an existing row. Ok so here's my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.BreakOut
(
    @userName varchar(50)
)
AS

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Clock WHERE clockDate = GETDATE() AND userName = @userName)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Clock SET breakOut = GETDATE() 
            WHERE clockDate = GETDATE() AND userName = @userName
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Clock (clockDate, userName, breakOut) 
            VALUES (GETDATE(), @userName, GETDATE())
    END
```

Here's my problem... If the user DID clock in for the day I get a primary key violation because the stored procedure is still trying to run the `INSERT` part of the statement and never runs the `UPDATE` line. I've tried it flipped with an `IF NOT EXISTS` as well with the same result. What's the trick to get IF-ELSE to work in a stored procedure? Can this be done they way I'm thinking or do I have to study `Merge` statement? My plan is to run the stored procedures from a simple Visual Basic program on each workstation. Maybe I'm getting in over my head :( To bad my boss is too cheap to just buy a time clock solution!

**EDIT:**

Thank you ALL for your help!! I'm falling in love with this site, questions get answers SO FAST!!! Here is my working stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.BreakOut
(
    @userName varchar(50)
)
AS

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Clock WHERE DateDiff(dd, GetDate(),clockDate) = 0 AND userName = @userName)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Clock SET breakOut = GETDATE() 
            WHERE DateDiff(dd, GetDate(),clockDate) = 0 AND userName = @userName
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Clock (clockDate, userName, breakOut) 
            VALUES (GETDATE(), @userName, GETDATE())
    END
```

Is this proper, or could it be improved more? Again Thank You ALL SO MUCH!!!

Comment: It's your IF statement - there wont exist a record with the time GETDATE() because that's now, as it returns the time, too! What you want to do is see if there exists a record already for that user on that date.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is probably the problem right here: WHERE clockDate = GETDATE()

GetDate returns the current date AND the current time, which wouldn't match up with clockDate.  You can compare the dates with DateDiff instead:

```
WHERE DateDiff(dd, GetDate(),clockDate) = 0
```

Comment: I would mark this the answer but I don't have the reputation, sorry! BUT THANK YOU!!!!!!!

Comment: Will this be a problem when I get to this day next month, or no? Is 'dd' referring to the day part of the date string?

Comment: You could user either one.  It's just checking to make sure they're the same day.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem would appear to be the following:

Let's imagine the user clocked in at 09:00

A record like the following might exist:

```
ClockDate    userName    clockIn    breakOut    breakIn    clockOut
12/08/2012   joe         09:00      NULL        NULL       NULL
```

Now your IF statement is doing this:

```
SELECT * FROM Clock WHERE clockDate = "20120812 17:24:13" AND userName = @userName
```

i.e. this record wont exist.

Instead, try this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Clock  WHERE clockDate = DATEADD(D, 0, DATEDIFF(D, 0, GETDATE())) AND userName = @userName)
```

You also need to make sure you are storing clockDate as just the date portion of GETDATE(), otherwise, you would need to adjust your query like so:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Clock WHERE DATEADD(D, 0, DATEDIFF(D, 0, clockDate)) = DATEADD(D, 0, DATEDIFF(D, 0, GETDATE())) AND userName = @userName)
```

Comment: Love the way you broke that down, Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Your update will never run because `GETDATE` returns a date *and time*.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `SP_GENRE_SELECT`(
    IN _Id INTEGER,
      IN _Name VARCHAR(50),
      IN _account VARCHAR (50),
      IN _Password VARCHAR (50),
      IN _LastConnexionDate DATETIME,
      IN _CreatedDate DATETIME,
      IN _UpdatedDate DATETIME,
      IN _CreatedUserId INTEGER,
      IN _UpdatedUserId INTEGER,
      IN _Status TINYINT
    )
BEGIN
      SELECT *
      FROM user
      WHERE Id LIKE IF(_Id IS NULL,'%',CAST(_Id AS VARCHAR(50)))
      AND
      Name LIKE IF(_Name IS NULL,'%',CONCAT('%',_Name,'%'))
      AND
      Account LIKE IF(_Account IS NULL,'%',CONCAT('%',_Account,'%'))
      AND
      LastConnexionDate LIKE IF(_LastConnexionDate IS NULL,'%',CONCAT('%',CAST(LastConnexionDate AS VARCHAR(50),'%')))
      AND
      CreatedDate LIKE IF(_CreatedDate IS NULL,'%',CONCAT('%',CAST(_CreatedDate AS VARCHAR(50),'%')))
      AND
      UpdatedDate LIKE IF(_UpdatedDate IS NULL,'%',CONCAT('%',CAST(_UpdatedDate AS VARCHAR(50),'%')))
      AND
      CreatedUserID LIKE IF(_CreatedUserID IS NULL,'%',CONCAT('%',CAST(_CreatedUserID AS VARCHAR(50),'%')))
      AND
      UpdatedUserID LIKE IF(_UpdatedUserID IS NULL,'%',CONCAT('%',CAST(_UpdatedUserID AS VARCHAR(50),'%')))
      AND
      Status LIKE IF(_Status IS NULL,'%',CAST(_Status AS VARCHAR(50),'%'))

END
```