# If NOT EXISTS in SQL not function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, if-statement, exists

I put this in the SQL Query editor of SQL Server 2008 and doesn't work:

```
If not EXISTS (Select * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA= 'dbo' AND TABLE_NAME='PK01')
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].['PK01'] (Articulo varchar(MAX),Referencia varchar(MAX),Lote varchar(MAX),Cantidad Int,Ubicacion varchar(MAX));
    INSERT INTO [UBICACIONES].[dbo].['PK01'] (Articulo,Referencia,Lote,Cantidad,Ubicacion)VALUES ('998','kk','ll',0,'pp')
else
    UPDATE [UBICACIONES].[dbo].['PK01'] Set Cantidad = (Cantidad + 23) WHERE Articulo LIKE '998'
```

Error I am getting:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'else'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2008 - IF NOT EXISTS INSERT ELSE UPDATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906506/sql-server-2008-if-not-exists-insert-else-update)

Comment: @mrogers no it isn't. `MERGE` would not be a suitable answer to this question.

Answer (score 5):

Your if statement only acts on the first statement after the IF unless you put a BEGIN/END around the statements.  This is the reason I like to have BEGIN/ENDs around even one statement IFs.

```
If not EXISTS (Select * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA= 'dbo' AND TABLE_NAME='PK01')
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].['PK01'] (Articulo varchar(MAX),Referencia varchar(MAX),Lote varchar(MAX),Cantidad Int,Ubicacion varchar(MAX));
    INSERT INTO [UBICACIONES].[dbo].['PK01'] (Articulo,Referencia,Lote,Cantidad,Ubicacion)VALUES ('998','kk','ll',0,'pp')
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    UPDATE [UBICACIONES].[dbo].['PK01'] Set Cantidad = (Cantidad + 23) WHERE Articulo LIKE '998'         
END
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but when I execute for the first time the query, it creates a table that is called PK01 and after insert the row with the values described in the query. But when I execute a second query the sql server put the follow message "
There is already an object named ''PK01'' in the database.
" and didn't execute the else statement.

Comment: @panki that's because the table that this creates will contain single quotes in the name, `['PK01']` should not have any quotes.

Answer (score 0):

This is highly not desirable.  You should really create tables before you use them.  But, you can do this using dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

If not EXISTS (Select * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND TABLE_NAME = 'PK01')
BEGIN
    SET @sql = 'CREATE TABLE [dbo].[''PK01''] (Articulo varchar(MAX),Referencia varchar(MAX),Lote varchar(MAX),Cantidad Int,Ubicacion varchar(MAX))';
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

    SET @sql = '
    INSERT INTO [UBICACIONES].[dbo].[''PK01''] (Articulo,Referencia,Lote,Cantidad,Ubicacion)VALUES (''998'',''kk'',''ll'',0,''pp'')';
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
END;
else
BEGIN
    SET @sql = '
    UPDATE [UBICACIONES].[dbo].[''PK01''] Set Cantidad = (Cantidad + 23) WHERE Articulo LIKE ''998''  '  ;

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;     
END;
```

Having done all that, I'll repeat.  This seems like a really bad application design.