# How to make sure the value am entering in an SQL database field is unique?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting a vlue from user and entering it inside my table in database. But I have to throw the user an error if he enters a value inside a data field which is already taken.

`UPDATE Class_records SET The_number= '456' where class='mech-4B'`

So here am updating my table by setting The_number to '456' to every records under mech-4B .

What kind of query statement can I do so that when another user enters the same number 456 say to "cse-4B" the query condition should fail ?

Comment: So multiple records can have the same value, but only if they're set in a single operation?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? I'd probably go with a trigger based solution here.

Comment: What is your RDBMS? Use a procedure to update your table, and check for existing of data before update.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen yes multiple records can have the same value(The_number) **only** when they have the same class name (mech 4b cse 4b etc). if someone assigns The_number to mech 4B that number can't be usable by any other now

Comment: @jarlh Microsoft SQL

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add unique constraint to combination of two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15800250/add-unique-constraint-to-combination-of-two-columns)

Comment: `CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateAWBUnique
  @AWB as nvarchar,
  @Internal as nvarchar
AS 
BEGIN 
     SET NOCOUNT ON 
     if((SELECT count(*)  From Def_tab WHERE  AWB=@AWB) == 0)
     BEGIN
           UPDATE Def_tab SET AWB= @AWB where Internal=@Internal 
     END
     ELSE
     BEGIN
           PRINT 'Already Exits'
     END

END
GO` 

I have written this procedure but somehow it keeps returning with errors namely with ERROR 102 SQLSTATE 420000

Answer (score 0):

You can run the query and check the **number of row** affected by the query. If the same query is runned, the number of row returned is most probably is zero. If zero you can throw error or expection to user.

```html
if (rowCount() > 0){
    //value is new 
}
else {
    //value is duplicated and throw error.
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't the sql query throw an exaception, instead of returning "0 affected rows"?

Comment: if you use pdo, we can call method rowCount() which return number of affected row, if not affected thus will return 0

Answer (score 0):

So you have to write a stored procedure for it:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateXYZTableWithUniqueness
    (@The_number AS INT,
     @class AS NVARCHAR)
AS 
BEGIN 
     SET NOCOUNT ON 

     IF ((SELECT COUNT(*)  
          FROM Class_records 
          WHERE The_number = @The_number) == 0)
     BEGIN
         UPDATE Class_records 
         SET The_number = @The_number 
         WHERE class = @class 
     END
     ELSE
     BEGIN
         PRINT 'Already Exits'
     END
END
GO
```

Comment: how does this code change if The_number is an NVARCHAR type

Comment: `CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateAWBUnique
  @AWB_No as nvarchar,
  @InternalPOD as nvarchar
AS 
BEGIN 
     SET NOCOUNT ON 
     if((SELECT count(*)  From Def_tab WHERE  AWB_No=@AWB_No) == 0)
     BEGIN
           UPDATE Def_tab SET AWB_No= @AWB_No where InternalPOD=@InternalPOD 
     END
     ELSE
     BEGIN
           PRINT 'Already Exits'
     END

END
GO` 

somehow it keeps returning with errors namely with ERROR 102 SQLSTATE 420000

Comment: **BE CAREFUL!!** [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](http://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use. Your `@class` here is a parameter of **exactly ONE character** in length !! Is that really what you wanted?????

Answer (score 0):

If you work with mysql, you can try to add "ignore" after your update :
"Update Ignore Class_records set ... ".

You can look this article : https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-insert-if-row-does-not-exist-upsert-in-mysql/

If you work with T-SQL, you can try to use the "If not exists ..." :
"If not Exists (select * from Class_Records where The_number ='456' and class ='mech-4B')
Begin
    UPDATE Class_records SET The_number= '456' where class='mech-4B'
end"

you can look this article : [SQL Server 2008 - IF NOT EXISTS INSERT ELSE UPDATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906506/sql-server-2008-if-not-exists-insert-else-update)

bye