# Incorrect syntax near the keyword Where. I want to prevent duplicate entry of one of the columns

Tags: vb.net

Please help me. I want to insert record in my database that prevents duplicate entries while inserting a record. Here's my code:

```
INSERT INTO Items_Tbl(Room_ID, Date_Purchased,Pc_Number)
Values('1', '2019-01-01', '1')
WHERE NOT EXISTS(Select PC_Number FROM Items_Tbl WHERE Room_ID = 1)
```

I don't want `PC_Number` to accept same entries.

Comment: An INSERT statement cannot have a WHERE clause

Comment: Please tell us what database are you using

Comment: I'm using sql..

Comment: Then what is the correct query to prevent duplicates on one of my column  'PC_Number' ?

Comment: SQL is not a database. SQL is the language used to query the database. Database is software like MySql or SqlServer. The syntax to use could be different for each database system

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm using SqlServer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906506/sql-server-2008-if-not-exists-insert-else-update

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is as such:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(Select PC_Number FROM Items_Tbl WHERE Room_ID = 1)
    INSERT INTO Items_Tbl(Room_ID, Date_Purchased,Pc_Number)
    Values('1', '2019-01-01', '1')
```

However, since you are using SQL Server, it's much better to create a unique, non-clustered index on the target table for the field `PC_Number`. You can also create a query/stored procedure separately to check if the PC_Number exists, if you need to reuse it elsewhere.