# How to import flat file with duplicate primary key records into SQL table

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, upsert, sql-server-2019

I have a SQL table with `Case_id` as a primary key. I'm using Visual Studio SSIS to import flat files into the table and a [Task Factory Upsert destination](https://docs.sentryone.com/help/task-factory-upsert) component to handle the insert/update part. The source file also has a column for the update dates.

[image]

If I have one record in the source file where the Case_id matches a `Case_id` already in the destination table the upsert works fine. But if the source file contains multiple records with the same primary key and different update dates, the package fails with a primary key violation. I don't see any functionality that allows me to select only the record with the most recent update date.

Any ideas on how I can handle that primary key violation? I'm thinking I may need to ditch the Upsert component and use some sort of MERGE statement with a MAX update date. I'm using SQL Server 2019, Visual Studio 2019, and SentryOne Task factory.

Comment: You want a procedure for the insert IF NOT EXISTS with an UPDATE for matched ID's. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906506/sql-server-2008-if-not-exists-insert-else-update

Comment: Is there any transformation performed by the SSIS package? Is the Task factory component required? You can simply bulk the flat file into a stagging table and run an SQL command to upsert the data into the destination table.

Comment: Seems you may need to add a filter task prior to your upsert and remove the rows with duplicate ID values. Perhaps send them to a file so someone can manually review them to verify that the "best" row was added/modified in the target.

Comment: @Hadi - No transformations. Pretty simple import. Just adding fields for FileName and LoadDate. I was hoping to get away from staging tables because there are close to 30 files going into 30 tables. Hoping there was a way to automatically scrub the file prior to load or use the update_date in a Merge statement.

Comment: @Don do all files have the same structure?

Comment: @Hadi - Unfortunately they are all different so I cannot use a single structure for all of them.

Comment: @Kendle - That looks like it could work for a table to table import, but can it be applied to a flat file import to table?

Comment: Import into a new table then do insert or update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to perform a simple full load pattern or just adopt the delta load.

- [Handling Data Load Types In Staging Database](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/handling-data-load-types-in-staging-database/)
- [Design The Full Load And Delta Load Patterns In SSIS](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/design-the-full-load-and-delta-load-patterns-in-ssis/)

Before loading your flat file to your staging table, you can SSIS Sort Transformation component :

> The Sort transformation sorts input data in ascending or descending
> order and copies the sorted data to the transformation output. You can
> apply multiple sorts to an input; each sort is identified by a numeral
> that determines the sort order. The column with the lowest number is
> sorted first, the sort column with the second lowest number is sorted
> next, and so on