# Compare values of several columns before inserting

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Lets say I have a temp table #t containing columns(MyGroup, FSGRoup, Account, BrokerCode, AccountType, NewInvestmentType, AccountOrder, LPI, LPII, LPIII) which contains the complete population of rows.

I have another table #t2 with the same layout and only a subset of rows contained in #t.  I want to insert rows that are in #t but not in #t2, into #t2, if there is no match on columns MyGroup, FSGRoup, Account, BrokerCode, AccountType, NewInvestmentType, AccountOrder.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a merge statement, as previously suggested, you can do something like the following.  The first query uses an outer join to get the rows that are in #t but not in #t2 and puts them into a third temp table, #t3.  The second query puts them from #t3 into #t2.

```
SELECT t.MyGroup, t.FSGRoup, t.Account, t.BrokerCode, t.AccountType, t.NewInvestmentType, t.AccountOrder, t.LPI, t.LPII, t.LPIII
INTO #t3
FROM #t t
LEFT OUTER JOIN #t2 t2
ON t.MyGroup = t2.MyGroup AND t.FSGRoup = t2.FSGRoup AND t.Account = t2.Account AND t.BrokerCode = t2.BrokerCode AND t.AccountType = t2.AccountType AND t.NewInvestmentType = t2.NewInvestmentType AND t.AccountOrder = t2.AccountOrder
WHERE t2.MyGroup IS NULL 
/*Assuming that MyGroup can't be null.  If it can, use a column that can't.*/

INSERT INTO #t2
SELECT MyGroup, FSGRoup, Account, BrokerCode, AccountType, NewInvestmentType, AccountOrder, LPI, LPII, LPIII
FROM #t3
```

Comment: I think the EXCEPT statement will do the trick.  Trying it now.  Will keep you posted.

Comment: @Chessguru: EXCEPT might work for you but this one appears to match your requirements more exactly. You don't need to use a third table though, just take the first SELECT, remove the `INTO #t3` and prefix it with `INSERT INTO #2` (it would be a good idea to list the target columns explicitly too, i.e. `INSERT INTO #t2 (MyGroup, ...) SELECT ...`).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on sql 2008+, this is exactly what a merge command is for (among other things)

For a nice simple explanation check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10218101/t-sql-merge-example-needed-to-help-comprehension) on using merge -- plenty more with a a little searching. The MS docs are a bit confusing though.

ADDED

Messed up, meant to include [this link](http://www.purplefrogsystems.com/blog/2011/12/introduction-to-t-sql-merge-basics/) too a nice article on merge basics.

Comment: Hi Gary, The example you point to checks on just one column.  I need to check multiple columns.

Comment: Why not look at the 2nd link I added earlier

Answer (score 0):

Merge is good solution but is recommended when there is multiple operations such as Insert, update and delete to be done in a single go.
Since the requirement here is to insert data into #t2 from #t which does not belong to #t a simple except would do

```
insert into #t2(
MyGroup, FSGRoup, Account, BrokerCode, AccountType, NewInvestmentType, AccountOrder, LPI, LPII, LPIII)

select MyGroup, FSGRoup, Account, BrokerCode, AccountType, NewInvestmentType, AccountOrder, LPI, LPII, LPIII from #t 
except
select MyGroup, FSGRoup, Account, BrokerCode, AccountType, NewInvestmentType, AccountOrder, LPI, LPII, LPIII from #t2
```

This will be much efficient and reliable than the other two solutions posted before