# prevent insert repeated data record(3column as 1 record) -vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, sqlcommand

I am doing an insert function which allow an admin to create time slot for classroom booking purpose.  The column would be room,time and date. How if i want to prevent repeated data insert?

for example: room 1,1pm, 12 july 2014  can insert twice.
what kind of query can i include to prevent it?
Here is my code:

```
    Dim con As New SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    con.ConnectionString = 
    con.Open()
    cmd.Connection = con

    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Room] ([room],[time],[date]) VALUES('" & ComboBox1.Text & "','" & ComboBox2.Text & "','" & DateTimePicker1.Text & "' )"
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MsgBox("Classroom and time is opened for student to book!")
    con.Close()
```

Comment: Do a `SELECT` statement first to check if there are any rows in the table with matching datetime and room combination. If the rows returned are more than zero, then don't go ahead with the insert

Comment: Sorry yeah - my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [MERGE T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10218101/t-sql-merge-example-needed-to-help-comprehension) command query like this. (Sql Server 2008)

```
cmd.CommandText = "MERGE INTO Room as Target " & _
      "USING (SELECT @rm as r, @tm as t, @dt as d) as Source " & _
      "ON Target.Room = Source.r AND Target.[time] = Source.t AND Target.[date] = Source.d " & _
      "WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN " & _
      "INSERT ([room],[time],[date]) VALUES (@rm, @tm, @dt);"
```

This query search the Room table for an exact match between your inputs and a record already present. If there is no match it executes the inserts. If there is a match nothing is done.

As you can see, this query doesn't use string concatenation as your example above. So you need to change also your code to use a parameterized query

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rm", ComboBox1.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tm", ComboBox2.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt", DateTimePicker1.Text)
Dim rowInserted = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
If rowInserted > 0 Then
   MessageBox.Show("Row inserted")
else
   MessageBox.Show("Already booked")
End If
```

But this approach leads to another question.
Are you sure that your fields `Time` and `Date` (I suggest to change these names) are NVARCHAR or other text type?.
They seems to be DateTime and so you need to pass a parameter with the appropriate date type.

Comment: i am using varchar for all three fields.Could you explain How to implement the parameter into my query and how it actually work?I dont understand this
int rowInserted = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
if(rowInserted > 0)

Comment: Nothing fancy. In your sql text you put, instead of values, a string that acts as a placeholder (@xxxx). The SqlCommand used to execute the text needs to have the Parameters collection filled with a SqlParameter for each placeholder. I have used the method AddWithValue but numerous constructors help to be more specific. When you use a parameterized query, the placeholders are matched against the collection and the corresponding values used in subst. This removes the need to have quotes around values and avoid Sql Injection Attacks.

Comment: cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Room] ([room],[time],[date]) VALUES('" & ComboBox1.Text & "','" & ComboBox2.Text & "','" & DateTimePicker1.Text & "' )"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rm", ComboBox1.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tm", ComboBox2.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt", DateTimePicker1.Text)
        Int(rowinserted = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery())

        If (rowinserted > 0) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Row inserted")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Already booked")

        End If

        con.Close()
Am I doing the correct way?

Comment: No, this has still the string concatenation part. `VALUES(@rm,@tm,@dt)`, and about rowinserted it is just the return value of ExecuteNonQuery. If the query inserts/updates/deletes rows you get here the count of these rows changed. Zero means that no rows has been changed/inserted/deleted.

Comment: cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Room] ([room],[time],[date]) VALUES(@rm,@tm,@dt)"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rm", ComboBox1.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tm", ComboBox2.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt", DateTimePicker1.Text)

        Int(a = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery())

        If (a > 0) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Row inserted")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Already booked")

Comment: That's correct.... well not quite. `int a = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` without the double open/close quote

Comment: But i still can insert same record into the table~

Comment: Mea culpa. I have made confusion between VB.NET and C# syntax. Now all the code above is in VB.NET syntax, please review.

Comment: still not working~even i insert the same record it still show MessageBox.Show("Row inserted")

Comment: I have tried to reproduce your table and executed the code above. It works as expected. Something is different on your side. Did you use the MERGE query?

Comment: Its working now. I missed up one symbol! Thank you for your help sir!! I feel so grateful for your helping.