# INSERT INTO - help inserting records into table where ID doesn't already exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have one database containing employee records that are entered by HR, and another database with a table that is to have matching information from those employees.  What I need help with, is gathering the employees from the HR database and then checking whether the employee already exists in the destination database, skipping if it does, and creating the record if it does not.

Here's what I have so far, but I'm stumped on how to check whether a record for the employee already exists in the destination database and how to get it to either skip or insert the new record:

QUERY 1:

```
 Insert INTO MainDB.dbo.employees (DriverID, Name, EntityID, EmployeeTypeID, SecureEmployee, Inactive,    CreatedDateTime, CreatedBy)
 SELECT    a.DET_NUMBERA AS DriverId
 , LTRIM(RTRIM(a.DET_SURNAMEA)) + ' ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(a.DET_G1_NAME1A)) AS FullName
 , 1 as EntityID
 , 1 as EmployeeTypeID
 , 0 as SecureEmployee
 , 0 as inactive
 , GETDATE() as CreatedDateTime
 , 'BRAD' as CreatedBy

 FROM
 (
 SELECT Emp_Details.DET_NUMBERA, DET_SURNAMEA, DET_G1_NAME1A, PYD_LOCN_CDA, PYD_COMPANYA , POS_STATUSA, POS_ENDD, Emp_Salary_Main.SMN_DATEC, Emp_Salary_Main.SMN_CLASSA, POS_STARTC
 FROM chrisbflprod.dbo.EMDET Emp_Details
INNER JOIN chrisbflprod.dbo.EMPAY Emp_Pay ON Emp_Details.DET_NUMBERA=Emp_Pay.DET_NUMBERA
INNER JOIN chrisbflprod.dbo.EMPOS Emp_Position ON Emp_Details.DET_NUMBERA=Emp_Position.DET_NUMBERA
INNER JOIN chrisbflprod.dbo.EMSAL Emp_Salary_Main ON Emp_Details.DET_NUMBERA=Emp_Salary_Main.DET_NUMBERA 
 WHERE Emp_Pay.PYD_COMPANYA='VIL'
 )  a INNER JOIN 
 (
 SELECT MAX(SMN_DATEC) AS MAX_DATE_SAL, DET_NUMBERA FROM chrisbflprod.dbo.EMSAL Emp_Salary
 --- (test employeeID)     WHERE DET_NUMBERA='0000026'
 GROUP BY DET_NUMBERA
 ) b ON a.DET_NUMBERA=b.DET_NUMBERA
INNER JOIN 
 (
 Select MAX(POS_STARTC) AS MAX_DATE_POS, DET_NUMBERA FROM chrisbflprod.dbo.EMPOS
 GROUP BY DET_NUMBERA
 ) c ON a.DET_NUMBERA=c.DET_NUMBERA
 WHERE a.DET_NUMBERA=b.DET_NUMBERA AND a.SMN_DATEC=b.MAX_DATE_SAL
 AND a.DET_NUMBERA=c.DET_NUMBERA AND a.POS_STARTC=c.MAX_DATE_POS AND
 a.POS_ENDD IS NULL OR a.POS_ENDD=''
 ORDER BY DriverID
```

The above process blindly reviews the records that exist in the source database, and simply inserts them into the destination database.  So as you can imagine, each time it is run, everything is duplicated in the destination database again and again.  What I need to do is check whether there is a record already existing in the destination database (matching on DriverID only).

Any help all you pros out there can provide will be so very greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look into the `WHEN NOT MATCHED` portion of the `MERGE` command. See the answer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10218101/t-sql-merge-example-needed-to-help-comprehension).

Comment: Thanks programmer43229, that helped tremendously and I now have it working correctly... brilliant.

Comment: RThomas did all the work. Send them thanks by voting up that answer since it helped you. (that is, if you haven't yet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this condition..

```
...... 
WHERE  a.DET_NUMBERA = b.DET_NUMBERA
       AND a.SMN_DATEC = b.MAX_DATE_SAL 
       and not exists (select 1 from MainDB.dbo.employees emp where a.DET_NUMBERA = emp.DriverID)
       ....
```

OR

may be here

```
WHERE  Emp_Pay.PYD_COMPANYA = 'VIL'
and    not exists (select 1 from MainDB.dbo.employees emp where Emp_Details.DET_NUMBERA = emp.DriverID)
```

Comment: Hi Pradeep - your answer is simple and works perfectly, thank you for taking the time to help me out as well.