# Concurrency issues with Update and Insert statements

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following SQL statement, which is either inserting or updating a single row in TableX based on a 'condition'

```
IF (Condition = True)
begin
    Update TableX
end
Else
begin
    Insert Into Tablex
End
```

This query is working fine when executed in SSMS. But as part of performance testing 100 concurrent users are executing this same query along with some other 'SELECT' queries pulling the data from 'TableX'. In this scenario the average execution time is increased by 10 fold.

I have tried 'NOLOCK' in select queries and 'ROWLOCK' in update statements but with no luck. Somebody suggested to remove clustered index created on 'Tablex'. But we can not afford this as it is going to slow down SELECT queries.

My question is what other optimization techniques I have to consider in this scenario to speed up the queries?

Comment: What does the condition involve? An SQL query in the same transaction?

Comment: I'm guessing that your query is being optimised for either the insert or update statement. Therefore half* the time it works efficiently and the other half* it gets a little lost and has to work things out from scratch.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: In condition i have simple SQL query which is checking for existence of a value in a table. But FYI, i have removed this condition (so that query fire one insert and one update one after the other) and verified the query but with no luck

Comment: How many rows are affected each time? Are you using cursors? Don't fiddle with locks, this is a classic blocking problem. Readers can't read rows as long as writers lock them. This shouldn't be a problem if you update only a few rows, but can be an issue if you update a lot of them. One solution is to use the `SNAPSHOT ISOLATION` transaction level while updating, which will allow readers to retrieve previous versions of the locked data. A better solution is to ensure you *don't* make massive changes that result in a lot of locks, by redesigning your tables/indexes or your queries

Comment: May I suggest using the `MERGE` command? See the answer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10218101/t-sql-merge-example-needed-to-help-comprehension)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: My Update/Insert just dealing with a single row and I am not using any cursor. I am using this within SP and all the Other SELECT statements which are accesing the same table have table hint 'WITH (NOLOCK)'