# What is the easiest (and fastest) way to update 20K employee data records from a CSV data dump in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv

I have an "employees" table with 50k+ records.  We only have 24k employees but some of the employees that are no longer here are tied to historical projects so I don't want to delete them.  And, of course, we've hired more employees that are working on NEW projects so they need to be added to the employees table.

I managed to convince HR to give me a CSV file with the employee data we keep in our table and now I need a way to update the existing records (new phone numbers, departments, etc...) and add new.

There are 3 criteria:

1. if the record exists in the CSV and the "employees" table, UPDATE the data;
2. if the record exists in the CSV and NOT the "employees" table, INSERT the data;
3. if the record exists in the "employees" table and NOT the CSV, set the record to "inactive."

This will be a regular (monthly) process so a Stored Procedure or a Function would be doable.

Suggestions please...

UPDATE:  The MERGE idea works but only solves 2/3 of the problem (it does not meet criteria #3 because I do not want to delete the record if the employee is not longer with the company).  When adding the 2nd UPDATE statement after the NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE, it returns an error indicating I cannot update the same record twice.

Any suggestions to this final piece of the puzzle?

Comment: Merge would solve as @csarwi mentioned. Also, You could load all the data in csv to a Stage table. Write a stored procedure that would perform UPDATE, INSERT and SET the IsActive flag on the target table to 0 to mark inactive employees. Perform INNER JOIN on Stage and Target table using EmployeeID to find existing records and UPDATE. LEFT JOIN on Stage and Target table using EmployeeID WHERE Target EmployeeID  IS NULL to INSERT data. RIGHT JOIN on Stage and Target table using EmployeeID WHERE Stage EmployeeID  IS NULL to mark inactive employees.

Answer (score 1):

What about using 'merge'?

```
MERGE target_table USING source_table
ON merge_condition
WHEN MATCHED
    THEN update_statement
WHEN NOT MATCHED
    THEN insert_statement
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
    THEN DELETE;
```

Comment: you might also want to check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967886/how-to-use-t-sql-merge-in-this-case/2967983#2967983

Comment: What is the difference between "NOT MATCHED" and "NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE"?

Comment: 'when not matched' means that the row is in your source table (the one you imported from your csv) but not in your target_table so you want to insert it. 
'when not mached by source' means it is in your tarbet_table but not in your source_table and you could delete it, in your case also update it and set inactive = 1.
note that this evaluation is of course based on your merge condition.

Comment: When I run the merge, I get an error, "The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source row. A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target table multiple times."
    MERGE employees 
    USING tempEmployees as source
    ON employees.empID = 123456789
    WHEN MATCHED
        THEN update
     SET employees.isActive = 1 
    --WHEN NOT MATCHED
    --    THEN insert_statement
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
        THEN update
     SET employees.isActive = 0;

Comment: I ran the above test merge using MY employeeID and I know for certain I'm only in the source table ONE TIME.